# i9300 bootloop and cannot install GApps?

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-3, rom-flashing, custom-roms, clockworkmod-recovery

I was trying to install [Resurrection Remix ROM](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s3/development/rom-resurrection-remix-5-2-1-t2972523) on my GT i9300 but I am stuck in a boot loop.

What have I done to my phone so far?

1. Rooted my phone using CF-AutoRoot
2. Installed CWM
3. Did a NANDroid backup
4. Factory reset from "Settings"
5. Factory Reset from CWM Recovery
6. Installed Resurrection from recovery (success)
7. Installed GApps from recovery (failed, status 7)
8. Reboot

I got the boot loader animation on reboot, an "Updating Apps" popup and then a bootloop.

**How do I solve this?**

*I did try flashing Resurrection from Recovery again but it did not help*

Update:

**ROM VERSION:**

```
[ROM] [5.0.2] [LOLLIPOP] [i9300] RESURRECTION REMIX 5.3.9[CM12-BASED]
```

**GAPPS VERSION:**

```
gapps-lp-20141109-signed
```

**ERROR LOG:**

```
Installing files...
Cleaning up and setting metadata...
set_meta_data_recursive: some changes failed
E: Error in /sdcard/0/gapps-lp-20141109-signed.zip
(Status 7)
Installation aborted.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is on Other `Resurrection Remix ROM's` is normal.You're right, i had the same problem with that.But try this (i fixed with below after two try) :
Just like this ; (**it maybe take a ten minute or more**)

- Download ***[the latest build of Resurrection Remix ROM](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?w=files&flid=22747)***
- Take a nandroid backup
- Flash ROM usingrecovery
- Flash Gapps ([Latest build, availabe in here](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Google_Apps) !)
- ***Wipe cache***
- ***Wipe dalvik cache***
- Reboot
- Enjoy.

But please remember, ask this question from Developer for Bug fixes or More information.
anyway, hope this helps.

Comment: Okay I tried TWRP. Installed CM11, reboot. 4.4.4 running fine.  GApps installs but don't show up in Menu.

Comment: downloaded Gapps incompatible with your Rom.if your **Main** Problem solved, accept or please ask a question or Follow xda developer topic for another reasons.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I'd be glad to extend this conversation beyond Android.SE. Exchange email? (:

Comment: I've cleaned up the comments here a bit, please use [chat] (you can make a separate room) for extended back-and-forth.